# Can main function take a String instead of String[]

Tags: java, parameters, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

`public static void main(String[] args)`
I know conventionally the main function takes in a parameter args that contains the supplied command line arguments as an array of String objects.

- I have not see main takes in any parameter other than `String[] args`. Why not a `String` or an array of `Integer`?
- If there is a way to specify input for the `main` function, please provide an example.

Comment: Because command line arguments are a series of strings, so they're given as a string array. You can parse them as integers inside your program if that's what you want.

Comment: It can be `String[]` or `String...`, and nothing else, because that's what the JLS says it has to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to your question: **NO**

Details:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

> The java command starts a Java application. It does this by starting a Java runtime environment, loading a specified class, and calling that class's **main** method.
>
> The method must be declared public and static, it must not return any value, and it **must accept a String array as a parameter**. The method declaration has the following form:
>
> public static void main(String[] args)

Answer (score 2):

As you already know that is the method definition of *main* and you *cannot* change it. However, you can convert the elements within the `args` array to any other *primitive* type considering that it's in a valid format to be converted to the *type* on the left side of the *assignment* operator.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, one of which is:

```
int input = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why not a String or an array of Integer?

Not an array of Integer because that array will cover only a subset of possible arguments (You can parse them and get an Integer, but you also need to check if they are Integers otherwise you'll get a NumberFormatException).

Not a string instead of a String array because it's better to have the command arguments separated instead of having them in one big string, in fact, a lot of times you need to handle the command arguments separately.

There's no alternative signature that the VM will recognize as `main` method. There is only one main signature allowed that is `public static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 1):

No, your main method cannot take just a String, main method must accept an array of String using array syntax or `varagrs` syntax, read following [JSL §12.1.4. Invoke Test.main](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4)

> Finally, after completion of the initialization for class Test (during
>   which other consequential loading, linking, and initializing may have
>   occurred), the method main of Test is invoked.
>
> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) **whose declared type is array of
>   String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable**:
>
> `public static void main(String[] args)`
>
> `public static void main(String... args)`

So, you can opt for either syntax but not just a String.

Just for your info you can create a method like `public static void main(String args)` but it wouldn't be regarded as "main" method of the class which JVM looks as the starting point. So, if you want to have a "main" method in your class then you have to choose from either of the above syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> I have not see main takes in any parameter other than String[] args. Why not a String or an array of Integer?

Yes, you can take any `String` or `Integer` as parameter, but that would become a different function `main()` method instead of the one used by java to start your program. After compilation, java search for `public static void main(String[] args){}` method to start with. If you change parameters then your program won't run at all. Now using array will cover only particular type of values that array can permit like `int[]` will only store `int`values, similarly `String` can have only one value, while you may want to have multiple arguments.

> If there is a way to specify input for the main function, please provide an example.

Yes, there are ways to pass argument using command line(for windows) and terminal(for linux/unix).

1. compile your java program by using `javac Filename.java`
2. run java program along with parameters `java FileName param1 param2 param3`
   (param1, param2, param3 are parameters that you want to pass).